# Edit cell in table with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

## update

I have a table written in javascript, now I want to edit the table. I have the following code in Javascript: but how can I type text in the cell ?

```
enter code here editCell: function(cell){
    if(cell.editMode != true) {                     
        cell.editmode = true;
        cell.innerHTML = "<p></p>";
    }
},
```

the table:

```
enter code here<body>
```

Cijfergegevens  
         
        {COLVAL}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this can help but it in jquery,

```
 $('td#id').html("value");

 result is 

 <td id="id">value</td>
```

in javascript might be

```
  document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "value";
```

FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just type text in a table cell. You need a textfield inside the cell with markup like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txt-input" />
```

Comment: thanks for the input field, but wich id can I use I don't have a fixed id for each row? (I updated my question).

Comment: you can use whatever id you want or you can skip the id if you don't need it. Id must be unique on the page and can be used to easily find element.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript after the HTML of your table

```
<table><tr><td id='cell1'></td></tr></table>
...
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('cell1').innerHTML = "write some text";
</script>
...
</body>
```